# What color bikes for Guys?

Tags: frames

I know color is a personal choice..
Obviously guys will not get pink but other than the famous black what color bikes should guys look for?

Comment: Of course, only [the cool guys](http://cdn.velonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/20176087-372662.jpg) [ride](http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/jul-2000-jan-ullrich-of-germany-and-riding-for-team-telekom-rides-in-picture-id1049338) [in pink](https://68.media.tumblr.com/86b670d732073be24d7ccbe2c9a21282/tumblr_nbg58ssBWd1tcj6cwo1_500.jpg). That said, this question will probably be closed as opinion-based. This means that there is no objectively true answer to your question. Please take the tour to see how the site works and what kinds of questions are welcome here.

Comment: Many questions are opinion based. If I ask how to calculate prime numbers between 1 and 1000, there are thousands of answers with programming languages, logic, functions etc that varies... I dont understand why there are some people who comment even if they dont have any interest in the question..

Comment: Guys should looks for whatever the heck color they want, red is not a feminine color, and even if it was, if that is what you like what does it matter. For the record my bike is silver. (Pivot Mach 5)

Comment: As a bloke, I would totally ride a pink bike.  Rule 5!  The only rules that mention colour are rule #8 (saddles/bars/ matching) and rule #28 (coloured socks)

Comment: Your girl friend is not questioning the 'Red' bike, its not really about the color of the bike (and  If you ask her whats wrong, she will say "Nothing")....

Comment: I never knew bike colors were gendered...

Comment: @StarAzure You don't understand because you don't under stand how Stack Exchange works. Please take a look at the [help centre](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): we don't do questions without reasonably objective answers. If you want to calculate prime numbers in a different way to me, you should be able to justify why your way is better. If you want to ride a different coloured bike to mine, you don't need any justification at all.

Comment: @David Richerby - As you can see, this questions has 3 answers already so your comment makes no sense. You are just one of those people. if you dont like a question, please stay away.. there is so many justifications about color that came up in the answers here -masculine, feminine, easy to see at night, stealing, etc came up.. So Im ignoring your comment

Comment: @StarAzure Visibility at night and desirability to thieves have nothing to do with what colour specifically men should choose.

Comment: @StarAzure if you asked "how to calculate prime numbers between 1 and 1000", it would be closed on [so] as unclear, too broad, etc. This question as currently stated is also like that: there's no clear objective what you want to achieve. If you want to make it clear that it's for masculinity, **then mention it the question** (although. I'm not sure it'd make this question better). Echoing Richerby's comment, "easy to see at night and security has nothing to do with bike color for men"

Comment: @Andrew T - If you dont like the question just stay away. I already got my answer. And YES - Lighter color bikes can be seen at night better. Regarding primer number question - Its not broad -  There is something call Algorithm/Logic that does not differ by programming language and that would be the answer. !!! Guys like you.. LOL...

Comment: But there are many algorithms to do that (e.g. [deciding a number is prime or not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)), and it's still too broad. Anyway, fine, I'll just leave this discussion with [Google Image for "bike for men"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bike+for+men&tbm=isch)

Comment: @StarAzure I cast the final vote to close. It is not that the question is not interesting, it is that any answer will be subjective (e.g., what exactly is masculinity- where I grew up it was driving a lifted truck - therefore no colour could ever make any bicycle masculine). Stack exchange requires that questions must be able to solicit definitive answers. These types of questions are well suited to forums and chat rooms.

Comment: And today this question has more than a thousand views and I was notified this is popular. BOOs to all above who thought this is not a sensible question.. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a perfectly reasonable question. Assuming that a person wants to appear masculine, not feminine, what color bicycle should they ride?

Curiously, in the [early 1900s](https://www.fastcodesign.com/1672751/how-pink-and-blue-became-gender-specific) pink was often considered to be a masculine color, and blue feminine.

After 1940, retailers began to push pink as a feminine color. That association is still [strong today](http://www.pinkisforboys.org/blog/when-did-pink-become-a-feminine-color), despite various sexual and gender revolutions.

Men and women have almost equal preference for the color red.  The color with the strongest gender bias is [purple](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/gender-and-color/).

If you are concerned with what other people will think about your masculinity, I suggest that blue is your best choice. Red is somewhat ambiguous. If you ride a red bike, some people (your girlfriend, as you pointed out) might question your masculinity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't care what colour people ride.  At least they're riding!

Black seems to appeal to thieves a bit more, so I'd not choose a dark bike by preference.

Also, dark bikes don't help you stand out in the dark.  As a safety choice I'd always choose a lighter-coloured frame.

Same goes for clothing - this recent trend of dark cycling kit seems a step backwards.  Reflectorised stuff helps, but it still depends on a light shining toward you at the same time someone's eyes are looking at you.

Personally I have 1 blue and 2 red frame for everyday bikes, and one more blue frame in the rebuild queue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is this so problematic question, you buy bike that you like, if you want pink, buy pink, personally, I ride black-red-white combination, and I really love it.[image]

Comment: That's the problem with this question: there's no distinctive/objective answer other than "buy any color what you like".